# Dynamically loading Sublime HTML5 Video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video-streaming

I am trying to dynamically load a bunch of sublime videos in from my page, and I am having trouble with the difference between the 'sublime' and 'sublimevideo' objects, and the docs aren't too helpful.

I am using this code to trigger the video loading and "unloading"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  sublimevideo.load();

  $('ul li').click(function() {
    var element = $(this)

    var video = element.data('video');
    var title = element.data('title');
    var description = element.data('description');


    var content = '<div class="overlay">' +
                    '<div class="content clearfix">' +
                      '<video id="video" width="640" height="400" style="margin: 0 auto;">' +
                        '<source src="../assets/video/' + video + '.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
                      '</video>' +
                      '<div class="meta">' +
                        '<h2 class="title">' + title + '</h2>' +
                        '<p class="description">Objective: ' + description + '</p>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<a class="close">Back</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                  '</div>'

    $('body').append(content);
    sublimevideo.load();

    sublimevideo.ready(function() {
      sublimevideo.prepareAndPlay();

      $('.overlay').animate({opacity: 1,
        left: 0 }, 400);

      $('.overlay').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
          opacity: 0,
          left: '-100px'},
          400,
          function() {
            sublimevideo.unprepare();
            $('body').find('.overlay').remove();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This works great if I just watch a video once. If I try to click on the video again, the overlay opens, and the video just loads forever (Seemingly) and never plays. I used to get a js error at this point, but no longer.

Any ideas why this might be? i am obviously having trouble with the preparing and un-preparing the video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know if you are still working on this, but I had a similar problem with loading videos dynamically...and yes, the documentation is sparse on examples, unfortunately. Like you, I remove the DOM element, re-build it, and then reload it. However, I included 'play' code within a callback of the prepare() function--maybe that is the issue for your code? My code inside of my .on('click') function, where my video tag's source tag has a class '.mp4_source':

```
var current_source = $('.mp4_source').attr('src');

if (current_source != video_location_mp4) {
    var current_width = $('#video_wrapper').width();
    var current_height = $('#video_wrapper').height();

    var new_video_wrapper = $('<div id="video_wrapper"></div>');
    var new_video_player = $('<video id="video_player"></video>')
                             .addClass('sublime')
                             .attr('width', current_width)
                             .attr('height', current_height)
                             .attr('preload', 'none')
                             .attr('data-uid', video_id)
                             .attr('data-name', viddata['subject'])
                             .attr('data-autoresize', 'fit');
    var new_source = $('<source src="' + video_location_mp4 + '"></source>')
                             .addClass('mp4_source');

    new_video_player.append(new_source);
    new_video_wrapper.append(new_video_player);

    $('#video_wrapper').remove();
    new_video_wrapper.insertBefore('#videoinfo');
    sublime.prepare('video_player', function(player) {
        player.on('metadata', function(player) {
            player.seekTo(timestamp);
        });
        player.play();
    });
} else {
    var player = sublime.player('video_player');
    player.seekTo(timestamp);
    player.play();
}
```